# Cross-browser CSS3 transition parse errors

Tags: browser, css, background

I've set cross-browser css3 bg transition

```
background: #999; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#dadada'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#dadada)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
```

But when i'm opening this page for example on Firefox it give me parse errors

Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. @ styles.css:43

Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. @ styles.css:43

[image]

How can i prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop those parse errors.  Firefox doesn't understand the filter property and from Firefox's perspective, that webkit syntax is wrong.  That's what happens when standards aren't finalized yet.